# Play framework to build application with no UI and need to accept requests using REST and ipc and/or message queues

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have to build a component that runs in a jvm, uses MongoDB as database and doesn't need a UI. It will be integrated into other products. I'm planning to build this using scala and related tools.

My first thoughts are to just let it expose REST API and let other products integrate using the API. While this is acceptable for some products, it isn't for others due to performance reasons. So I have to enable other components to communicate to this using either http or ipc or message queues. How can achieve this without much duplication of business logic.

Would Play framework be the right choice for this even though there is no UI involved and there is a need to accept messages via http or ipc or message queues?

Answer (score 1):

Using Play for that is ok but there are frameworks better fit for what you are planning to do, as you already said, play has a lot of support for frontend features you don't need.
It will not so much affect the runtime speed as the time you will need for programming, compiling, building and deployment.

There are some framworks that might fit you needs better:

- **Scalatra** Nice, easy to use, integrates good with JavaEE-Stack http://www.scalatra.org/
- **Finatra** Cool if you have the twitter stack running. Metrics and other stuff almost for free  http://finatra.info/
- **Skinny Framework** : Looks nice, never tried myself
- **Spray** : Cool features to come, a little elitist